# Troubleshoot PDO query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for collecting various general settings for a website. I do some validation with JQuery, then POST the data to a PHP script for processing. It all seems to work fine, except that all fields in the table are filled with `NULL` instead of actual values.

My table has but 3 columns - `TblID, SettingName, SettingValue`. The latter can be NULL.

Here's the code:

```
/*
* This first array is a list of all the settings. 
* The form inputs are named thus, and I want the `SettingName` value to 
* also be pulled from this list. 
* For example: 
* input[name="BrowserTitle"] = 'My Site' => 
* $_POST['BrowserTitle'] = 'My Site' => 
* SettingName = BrowserTitle, SettingValue = 'MySite'
*/

$settings_arr = array(
    'BrowserTitle', 'SiteTitle', 'SiteBlurb',
    'SiteEmail', 'SiteAddress', 'SiteMobile', 'SiteLandline', 'SiteFax',
    'SiteSocialFacebookLink', 'SiteSocialYouTubeLink', 'SiteSocialTwitterLink',
    'SiteSEOKeywords', 'SiteSEOBlurb'
);
$settings = join('\',\'',$settings_arr);

//clear old values
$q = $su_gl_conn -> prepare(" DELETE FROM su_settings WHERE SettingName IN ('" . $settings . "') ");
$q               -> execute(); //works so far


//begin insert statement:
$tokens = array();
$sql = "INSERT INTO su_settings ( SettingName, SettingValue ) VALUES ";
foreach($settings_arr as $i => $settingName)
{
    $sql.= "( '" . $settingName . "', :settingValue" . $i . " ),";
    $tokens[':settingValue' . $i] = (!empty($_POST[$settingName])) ? $_POST[$settingName] : NULL;
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

$q = $su_gl_conn -> prepare($sql);
foreach($tokens as $tokenName => $tokenValue)
{
    $q -> bindParam( $tokenName, $tokenValue, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
}
$q -> execute();
```

The query does not fail, and all rows are filled - every `SettingName` is filled correctly with the right string, but every `SettingValue` is set to `NULL`. If I echo my `$tokens` array however, it does show the inputted values being mapped over correctly: the proper tokennames to the correct values.

The actual query when echoed:

```
INSERT INTO su_settings ( SettingName, SettingValue ) VALUES ( 'BrowserTitle', :settingValue0 ),( 'SiteTitle', :settingValue1 ),( 'SiteBlurb', :settingValue2 ),( 'SiteEmail', :settingValue3 ),( 'SiteAddress', :settingValue4 ),( 'SiteMobile', :settingValue5 ),( 'SiteLandline', :settingValue6 ),( 'SiteFax', :settingValue7 ),( 'SiteSocialFacebookLink', :settingValue8 ),( 'SiteSocialYouTubeLink', :settingValue9 ),( 'SiteSocialTwitterLink', :settingValue10 ),( 'SiteSEOKeywords', :settingValue11 ),( 'SiteSEOBlurb', :settingValue12 )
```

And the token array (with only 2 actual values):

```
:settingValue0=My Site:settingValue1=My Site:settingValue2=:settingValue3=:settingValue4=:settingValue5=:settingValue6=:settingValue7=:settingValue8=:settingValue9=:settingValue10=:settingValue11=:settingValue12=
```

I just need fresh eyes at this point, I can't figure why it's not working - it's probably something small. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: look at the difference between [bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).